# How to update document in Mongodb with condition

Tags: mongodb

There is a `log` collection in my mongodb which has an unique index named `log_id`. I want to achieve this goal:
Whenever I update the documents, if document with the same `log_id` already exists, then `{$inc: {count: 1}}`. If not, then insert the new document with `{count: 1}`. Can I do this in a single command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can this in a single query with `{upsert : true}` option.

and [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/inc/) syntax is `{ $inc: { <field1>: <amount1>, <field2>: <amount2>, ... } }` so you should use `{$inc: {count: 1}}` instead of `{count: {$inc: 1}}`

try it:

```
db.log.update(
      {"log_id": compareLogId},
      {$inc: {count: 1}},
      {upsert:true}
)
```

Comment: How if the `log_id` doesn't exist, the new document won't be `{count:1}` cause there will be more cols.

Comment: if not matched then what do you want ? @Charles

Comment: Insert a new document.

Comment: above query will insert new document if not matched . for example: if in your db log_id is 12 and if you check with `{"log_id":14}` then insert new document like `{"log_id":14, "count:1"}` @Charles